# I need some JS and Jquery support

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, jquery-selectors

```
$(function(){
   function First(){
        $(this).next().attr("src", "point.png");
   }
});
```

This code isnt working, can you help me?

Here is html:

```
         Username: <input type="text" name="username" onkeypress="First()">
     <img src="" class="vimg">
     <br>
```

Comment: Declare your function outside `$(function(){ ... });` scope

Comment: Learn about scoping: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your function `First` is scoped within the anonymous function. In order for `onkeypress="First()"` to work, it must be a global function.

I generally prefer to scope my functions as you have (to prevent polluting the global namespace), so what most people do in this case is to set the `onkeypress` event through JavaScript (from inside your anonymous method). It would look something like this:

```
$(function(){
   function First(){
        $(this).next().attr("src", "point.png");
   };

   $("input[name='username']").on('keypress', First);
});
```